# Overlay the template over the reference image using Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, tracking, scikit-image, homography

So, I am stuck at a place where I need to superimpose a image in a homographed form to reduce the noise and allow us to reduce the load.

The image where I need to superimpose:

[image: 1]

The image which I will be superimposing:

[image: 2]

Now, the basketball court has to be superimposed over the 2d drawing, hence allowing me to track the court dynamically over video, thereby get a reference point to track the players inside the court.

Here is the code that I used as of now to track the area

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from skimage.io import imread, imshow, imsave
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Rectangle
    from skimage import transform
    from skimage.color import rgb2gray
    from skimage.feature import match_template
    from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
    import numpy as np
    import glob
    import os
    from natsort import natsorted 
    def track_camera(image_path, num, path='./cam_trackings/'):
        reference_image = imread("full-court.jpg")
        # plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
        # imshow(reference_image);
        reference_image_gray = rgb2gray(reference_image)
        # plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
        # imshow(reference_image_gray);
    
        template = rgb2gray(imread(image_path))
        # imshow(template);
    
        result = match_template(reference_image_gray, template)
        # plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
        # imshow(result, cmap='magma');
    
        x, y = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(result), result.shape)
        template_width, template_height = template.shape
        rect = plt.Rectangle((y, x), template_height, template_width, 
                        color='r', fc='none')
        plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
        plt.gca().add_patch(rect)
        imshow(reference_image_gray);
        # imsave(path+'cam_tracking'+str(num)+'.png', reference_image_gray)
        plt.savefig(path+'cam_tracking'+str(num)+'.png')
        plt.close()
```

And the output of this is as below (Tracked area):

[image: 3]

Comment: [mre] please. where does `match_template` come from?

Comment: the `match_template` is taken from the skimage library.

Comment: there also happens to be incorrect highlighting of the area in the template, how to highlight the proper area, any algorithms with pre-trained models?

Comment: match_template can't be used for perspective-distorted images. it can only recover translation, **not** scale or rotation or shearing or perspective.

Comment: So for this case with which library should I go for correction of perspective with respect to the template?

Comment: this isn't a matter of libraries but of knowledge in computer vision. depending on the level of quality you require of this tracking task, you'll need to pick and combine different approaches. the simplest I can think of is feature matching, filtering of matches (Lowe's ratio test), and `cv.findHomography`. this is simply not achievable unless you actually learn about Computer Vision, not just some libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will do surely. I am in mids of learning, tried manual homographing, but it's too time consuming and not automated, thought of ai based solution, but nope resource restrictions and so on. Hence landed on finding pre trained models for finding or creating a ln automatic homograph solution. Considering the Region Of Interest